# Rolling three dice and getting exactly two 4s - am I doing this right?

Tags: probability

> Toss $3$ dice. What's the probability that a "4" will come up exactly
> twice?

Since we need two of the dice to come up 4, and the third can be any number except 4 we can have the following options:

[4, 4, $\neq$ 4], [4, $\neq$ 4, 4], or [$\neq$ 4, 4, 4]. Right?

P of getting a 4 is $1/6$ and P of not getting a 4 is $5/6$ (assuming we have a $6$-sided die and each event is independent).

Let's take the first option: [4, 4, $\neq$ 4]

$\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{216}$  or $~0.02315$

And accounting for the other options is just multiplying by $3$ to get $0.06945$?

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Good, now multiply your result by 3 to account for the 3 possibilities

Comment: So far, so good...

Comment: You correctly calculated the probability of the first option.

Comment: More generally...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score -2):

You are very close, but in order to solve it you need to use the binomial distribution: $$\binom{\textrm{No. of attempts}}{\textrm{number of successes}} \cdot  (\textrm{success chance})^{\textrm{No. of successes}} \cdot  (1 - \textrm{success chance})^{\textrm{No. of failures}}.$$ In your case, it is
$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot  \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2} \cdot  \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{1} = 3 \cdot  \frac{1}{36} \cdot  \frac{5}{6} = \frac{15}{216} \approx 0.07=7\%$$

Comment: The solution posted in the question is correct.  Using the binomial distribution is a more efficient method of solution.

Comment: They _are_ using the bobbin binomial distribution. They just don't explicitly write the binomial coefficient as a binomial coefficient.